# getting a lot of errors from a request and i am not good at requests

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, fetch-api

When I request something it comes up with 3 errors.

I think it doesn't allow me to do a request from specific places but I am not sure I am pretty new to requests and I want to put this in my content script.
[image: the 3 errors]

I tried doing it on other places but it didn't work, I expected to get a JSON response back.

And also if I just go to the link it gives me the info I need, if the only way to do it is through background page in my web extension then that's fine but I prefer it on the content script.

Comment: Hi, welcome to Stack Overflow! [Please do not upload images of code/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/8289918) It makes it harder for others to read your code, reproduce the scenario, and answer your question. [Edit] your question to include your code [formatted as code blocks](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/251361/8289918).

Comment: You've to give a permission for that URL in the manifest file of the extension. That is, include the URL in `permissions` array.

Answer (score -1):

It is a CORS error that is Cross-Origin Resource Sharing, that means you are requesting a url which has only allowed a certain other URLs to consume its resources.
Try adding [Moesif Cors extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/moesif-origin-cors-change/digfbfaphojjndkpccljibejjbppifbc) to google chrome and then request the API, this extension bypass the CORS policy. If it doesn't, that means you cannot hit that API, outside access to resource is restricted.

Comment: Oh okay there are stuff that can bypass it, that's cool, but if it doesn't work is there any chance it will work on a background page?

Comment: It is doesn't bypass it that means you cannot hit that API, outside access to resource is restricted. No chance for it to work, it is restricted by a policy that is accepted globally.